# Is master theorem applicable for $T(n) = 8T(\frac{n-\sqrt n}4) + n^2$?

Tags: recurrence-relation

Is master theorem applicable for this example?

$$T(n)= 8T \biggl(\frac{n-\sqrt n}4\biggr)+ n^2$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The master theorem isn't applicable, but the [Akra–Bazzi theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method) is, and it shows that your recurrence has the same solution (asymptotically) as the simpler one without the square root, that can be solved using the master theorem.

Comment: what about if none f(n) given? `T(n)= T(n/4) lgn `

Comment: one more questioonn

Answer (score 0):

Master theorem not applicable, [see](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.046/spring02/handouts/mastersol.pdf)
[image]